# Switched from cinnamon to dwm, missing the way cinnamon unified the appearance of apps

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, cinnamon, dwm, gsettings

I'm running linux mint's cinnamon desktop. In system settings I have Font Selection->Text Scaling Factor set to 1.2 and under Accessibility->Visual Aids->Large text toggled on. The reason is that I like big menus/fonts/texts so I can use my 2560x1440 monitor without having to put on my reading glasses.

Those settings arent used when I run programs in dwm (firefox, thunderbird, gnome-terminal). They are apparently using their respective defaults.

How do I go about making the programs in dwm look the same as they do in cinnamon?

I have determined that changing Font Selection->Text Scaling Factor is equivalent to running the following in terminal
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2

When I run this in dwm there is no change, which makes sense since I'm in dwm not cinnamon.

Is there a way for me to set something similar in dwm for firefox and such?

I tried:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2

but it didn't change anything.

I know I can change firefox's appearance in about:config but I want to make changes that only apply when firefox is running in dwm and leave the appearance of firefox in cinnamon unchanged.

Comment: I know the problem, but not with dwm in particular. In XFCE it just works out of the box. Maybe [setting the DPI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/#1292397) can work for you.